# On print window close event in Chrome, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, printing

I have that Chrome print dialog window which is kinda OK but I need event when that window is canceled or closed in order to trigger other function. Is it possible to do something like this.

Comment: I don't think such an event exists. Can you elaborate on your use-case?

Comment: You could try `<body onUnload="yourFunction()">`, though I never really understood how it works. I just remember seeing it in a different question.

Comment: There is no event to say if they printed or not.

Comment: @frits I'm printing some Google map in one window, I have screen view and print view. I load print view dynamically (some iframes) and triggering that print view via button -> window.print(). So If the user cancel or close print preview I would like to remove - unload that print view that I generated. I have other solutions but I was wondering is it possible ta call such an event. Maybe to pass some data to print preview window via window.print function or something?

Comment: Can you the print preview right after you call `window.print()`? Or will that mess up the print? I'm not sure if browsers _freeze_ the content once you get print preview.